# Shape casting a capsule against convex polyhedra

Tags: algorithm, math, vector, geometry, collision-detection

Let's say I have a upright capsule shape (swept sphere) that I would like to cast it along a velocity vector. I would like to be able to find the ***point of contact*** and a ***surface normal*** for any convex shapes it would intersect along this path. I would also like to find the distance the swept caspule traveled to the point of first contact.

Heres a quick diagram of a capsule being casted against a large convex polyhedra (only one face is drawn) [image]

What kind of algorithm or process could do this? I assume it would be similar to a sphere-cast, but i can't find much on that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are considering capsules and convex polyhedra, I suppose you could use something based on [GJK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm). You would get the point of contact and a surface normal during a collision, and the minimum distance between the objects and the associated witness points if there is no collision.

You can also take a look at this publication on [Interactive and Continuous Collision Detection for Avatars in Virtual Environments](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/AVATAR/).

Answer (score -1):

Right if its the same as your diagram then finding where it collides is the easy part. Get the circles x and y coordinates and plus '+' the radius of the circle. If that point is at the line of the path then its a collision. The line will have to be found using the line equation here y = mx+c.

The distance can be calculated by setting an intial values of x and y. and then when the object hits set final variables to x and y again. then just the lenght of a line formula to calculate the distance travelled.

The problem is im going on what i know from C++ and i dont know what your programming in.

i think you wanted something else but cant work out what that is from paragraph.

Comment: Looks like you completely misunderstood the question.